# Count Duplicates from a union all Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to count the duplicates form a union all query. If i add a group by it elimates the duplicates. I need a count of the two duplicates from the two accounts, but the account might have duplicates in it which im not concerned about. hence the distinct

```
Select CRID.CId as CIds FROM
(
    Select Distinct([CId]) as CId From [dbo].[MyTable] Where AccountId = 'E7888A78-043F-4C34-BB72-1EDC97D32EDB'
    UNION ALL
    Select Distinct([CId]) as CId From [dbo].[MyTable] Where AccountId = 'CC94E667-7776-4427-A6D9-6492C5CDA617'
) CRID
Having Count(CRID.CId > 1) -- Can't use having
```

Comment: Do a row_number() and count how many there is above 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have only two tables, you could do:

```
select count(*) - count(distinct cid) as num_duplicates
from ((Select Distinct([CId]) as CId 
       from [dbo].[MyTable]
       Where AccountId = 'E7888A78-043F-4C34-BB72-1EDC97D32EDB'
      ) union all
      (Select Distinct([CId]) as CId
       from [dbo].[MyTable]
       Where AccountId = 'CC94E667-7776-4427-A6D9-6492C5CDA617'
      )
     ) CRID;
```

However, you seem to want `Cid`s that have both `AccountId`s.  I would just go for:

```
select cid
from dbo.MyTable
where AccountId in ('E7888A78-043F-4C34-BB72-1EDC97D32EDB', 'CC94E667-7776-4427-A6D9-6492C5CDA617')
group by cid
having count(distinct AccountId) > 1;
```

If you want the count, use a subquery:

```
select count(*)
from (select cid
      from dbo.MyTable
      where AccountId in ('E7888A78-043F-4C34-BB72-1EDC97D32EDB', 'CC94E667-7776-4427-A6D9-6492C5CDA617')
      group by cid
      having count(distinct AccountId) > 1
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Option 3 is perfect. Question if you've time to answer, why doesn't just counting the result from option 2 yield the same result as 3. I checked and i know it doesn't just don't know why. Thanks

 select count(cid)
from dbo.MyTable
where AccountId in ('E7888A78-043F-4C34-BB72-1EDC97D32EDB', 'CC94E667-7776-4427-A6D9-6492C5CDA617')
group by cid
having count(distinct AccountId) > 1;